# Finding the sum in R using conditions

Tags: r, sum, rstudio

I would like to know how to do a conditional sum in R. Let's say I want only the sum of Store ID = 111111 in the year 2012. How would I do this?

```
YEAR       STORE ID       AMOUNT
2011       111111         11
2011       222222         12
2012       111111         4 
2012       222222         4 
2012       111111         45
2012       333333         7
```

Comment: My comment and the answer to your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759867/omitting-and-finding-average-in-r) were difficult to extend from `mean` to `sum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset the data.frame then sum the resulting column. Call that data.frame mydf

```
sum(mydf[ mydf$'STORE ID' == 111111 & mydf$YEAR == 2012, 3])
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! However I was wondering what the '3' in this part is for: mydf$YEAR == 2012, 3])

Comment: 3 is in the columns part of subsetting a data.frame so it refers to the 3rd column.

Comment: Using "AMOUNT" instead of 3 would be more readable and less prone to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `data.table` package in case:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(dt, YEAR, STORE_ID)[.(2012, 111111), sum(AMOUNT)]
```

We first `setkey()` which sorts the data.table in increasing order based on the columns provided and marks those column as sorted so that we can use *fast binary search based joins, which we do in the next step with `.(2012, 111111)` which looks for 2012 in the first key column = `YEAR` and 111111 in the second = `STORE_ID` using binary search. And on those rows, we compute the sum of column `AMOUNT`.

You can also do it the typical base R way (which uses vector scan as opposed to binary search):

```
dt[YEAR == 2012 & STORE_ID == 1, sum(AMOUNT)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the `dplyr` and `magrittr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

y <- data_frame(YEAR = c(2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), 
                STORE_ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3), AMOUNT = c(11, 12, 4, 4, 45, 7))

y %>% filter(YEAR == 2012, STORE_ID == 1) %$% sum(AMOUNT)
```